# Excel vba how to repeat an if then else condition on rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to repeat my 'if then else' condition on the 30 rows that follow.
This is my code (I am new to this).

```
Dim score As Range, result As Double
If Range("A2") = "2a" Then
Range("C2") = 20

Else
If Range("A2") = "3c" Then
Range("C2") = 23
```

So at the moment when I enter 2a / 3c in cell A2, the number 20 / 23 comes up in cell C2.
I would like the same thing to happen in row 3, 4, 5 ... 30. When I enter 2a / 3c in cell A5, the number 20 / 23 comes up in cell C5.
Is it possible with a loop or another type of code? Or will I have to copy this over and over for each row?

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic *for-next* loop that would accomplish what you ask...

```
For i = 2 To 30
    If Range("A" & i) = "2a" Then
        Range("C" & i) = 20
    End If
    If Range("A" & i) = "3c" Then
        Range("C" & i) = 23
    End If
Next
```

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) I picked at random from a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well

```
  Dim score As Range, c As Range, x
Set score = Range("A2:A32").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
For Each c In score.Cells
    x = IIf(c = "2a", 20, IIf(c = "3c", 23, ""))
    c.Offset(0, 2) = x
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 if not intersect(target,range("A2:A32")) is Nothing then target.offset(,2)=iif(instr("2a3a",target)>0,20+3*abs(target="3c"),"")
End sub
```